# Calculate proportions within subsets of a data frame

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to obtain proportions within subsets of a data frame. For example, in this made-up data frame:

```
DF<-data.frame(category1=rep(c("A","B"),each=9),
    category2=rep(rep(LETTERS[24:26],each=3),2),
     animal=rep(c("dog","cat","mouse"),6),number=sample(18))
```

I would like like to calculate the proportion of each of the three animals for each `category1` by `category2` combination (e.g., out of all animals that are both "A" and "X", what proportion are dogs?). With `prop.table` on column 4 of the data frame I can get the proportion that each row makes up of the total "number" column, but I have not found a way to do this for subsets based on category 1 and 2. I also tried splitting the data by `category1` and `category2` using this:

```
splitDF<-split(DF,list(DF$category1,DF$category2))
```

And I was hoping I could then apply a function with `prop.table` to get the proportions of each animal within each split group, but I cannot get `prop.table` working because I can't seem to specify which column of data to apply the function to within the split groups. Does anyone have any tips? Maybe this is possible with `plyr` or something similar? I can't find anything in the help forums about ways to get proportions *within* subsets of data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use function `ddply()` from library `plyr` to calculate proportions for each combination and then add new column to data frame.

```
 library(plyr)     
 DF<-ddply(DF,.(category1,category2),transform,prop=number/sum(number))
 DF
   category1 category2 animal number       prop
1          A         X    dog     17 0.44736842
2          A         X    cat      3 0.07894737
3          A         X  mouse     18 0.47368421
4          A         Y    dog      2 0.14285714
```

Comment: This is really nice and clean. Thanks very much, Didzis! plyr seems to be the solution to a lot of these kinds of issues, but it's taking me a while to get used to it!

Comment: sorry to necro this post - could you explain the '.' following 'DF,'?

Comment: @ReputableMisnomer `.()` syntax around variables is used to allow variable names withouh quotes. See the help file of function ddply (examples part).

Answer (score 3):

does this produce your desired output ?

```
 DF$proportion<-as.vector(unlist(tapply(DF$number,paste(DF$category1,DF$category2,sep="."),FUN=function(x){x/sum(x)})));
```

Comment: Yes, it does (as does Didzis's answer using plyr). Thank you very much for your help!