# Obtaining proportions within subsets of a data frame

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to obtain proportions within subsets of a data frame. The inputs are Grade, Fully Paid and Charged Off. I tried using

```
DF$proportion<-as.vector(unlist(tapply(DF$Grade,paste(DF$Fully Paid ,DF$ Charged Off,sep="."),FUN=function(x){x/sum(x)}))
```

based on an answer given to this same question in a previous post [Calculate proportions within subsets of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009011/calculate-proportions-within-subsets-of-a-data-frame/63833691#63833691) but not having luck. I am guessing because Grade is a character not a number in my data.

Comment: Do you have a sample data that you can share?

Comment: Yes, here is the data I am using, grades being A-G with count of Charged Off and Fully Paid below. 

A             B      C             D         E         F     G.     
                                           
 Charged Off   1486    3657   5344    3375  1238   214    27

  Fully Paid       24265 26453 23025   9665  2628   296    53

Comment: You have to give a desired output too. Also The post that you are referring is just using 1 numeric column to get the proportion. You have 2 numeric columns. Which column are you trying to get the proportions. If you can be more specific I can help you. You are using `paste` for numeric which is not correct as it will concatenate 2 numbers to a decimal value.

Comment: thanks, pretty new to R still hence all these errors. Let me re-explain better. I used code
> LT <- table(lcdf$loan_status, lcdf$grade)
> prop.table(LT) the prop table gives me the proportions of each variable against the entire table, but what I need the proportions just for each column. So I need to know the proportion of each loan status category for each grade. The commands I used earlier were just shots in the dark based off of the most similar post I could find from the past. I know the solution is easy here, just don't know what it is.

Comment: Did you try the solution.

Comment: yeah, didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, Here is the code you should try for each column.

```
DF$Charged_off_proportion <- as.vector(unlist(tapply(DF$Charged_Off,DF$Grade,FUN=function(x){x/sum(x)})))
```

Similarly you can change the column names for other columns like

```
DF$Fully_Paid_proportion <- as.vector(unlist(tapply(DF$Fully_Paid,DF$Grade,FUN=function(x){x/sum(x)})))
```